# Best way to compare meaning of text documents?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, text-mining

I'm trying to find the best way to compare two text documents using AI and machine learning methods. I've used the TF-IDF-Cosine Similarity and other similarity measures, but this compares the documents at a word (or n-gram) level.

I'm looking for a method that allows me to compare the *meaning* of the documents. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

You should start reading about word2vec model.
use [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html), get the [pretrained model](https://github.com/mmihaltz/word2vec-GoogleNews-vectors) of google.
For vectoring a document, use [Doc2vec()](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) function. 
After getting vectors for all your document, use some distance metric like cosine distance or euclidean distance for comparison.

Answer (score 6):

This is very difficult. There is actually no computational definition of "meaning". You should dive into text mining, summarization and libraries like gensim, spacy or pattern.

In my opinion, the more readily useable libraries available out there ie. higher return on investesment (ROI), that is if you are a newbie you might want to look at tools around chatbots they want to **extract from natural language structured data**. That is what is the most similar to "meaning". One example free software tool to achieve that is [rasa natural language understanding](https://nlu.rasa.ai/).

[image]

The drawback of such tools is that they somewhat work but only in the domain where they were trained and prepared to work. And in particular they do not aim at comparing documents like you want.

> I'm trying to find the best way to compare two text documents using AI

You must come up with a more precise task and from there find out which technic apply best to your use case. Do you want to classify documents in predefined categories. Do you to compute some similarity between two documents? Given an input document, do you want to find most similar documents in a database. Do you want to extract important topics or keywords in the document? Do you want to summarize the document? Is it an abstractig summary or key phrase extraction?

In particular, there is no software that allows to extract somekind of *semantic fingerprint* from any document. Depending on the end goal, the way to achieve it might be completly different.

You must narrow the precise goal you are trying to achieve; From there, you will be able to ask another question (or improve this one) to describe precisly your goal.

Text understanding is AI-Complete. So, just saying to the computer "tell me something about this two documents" doesn't work.

Like other have said, word2vec and other word embeddings are tools to achieve many goals in NLP but it only a mean for an end. You must define the input and output of the system you are trying to design to be able to start working on the implementation.

There is two other Stack Overflow communities that you might want to dig:

- [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Given the tfidf value for each token in your corpus (or the most meaningful ones) you can compute a sparse representation for a document.
This is implemented in the sklearn [TFIDFVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).

As other users have pointed out, this is not the best solution to your task.
You should take into account embeddings.

The easiest solution consists in using an embedding at the words level, such as the one provided by the [FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText) framework.
Then you can create an embedding for the whole document by summing together the embedding of the single words which compose it.

An alterative consists in training an embedding directly at the document level, using some Doc2Vec framework such as the [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) or [DL4J](https://deeplearning4j.org/doc2vec) one.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use LDA Or LSI Models for text corpus. these methods(and other methods like wor2vec and doc2vec) can summarize documents to fixed length vectors with respect to it's meaning and topics that this document belongs to.

read more:
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html

Answer (score 0):

I heard there are [three approaches from Dr. Golden](https://www.learningmachines101.com/lm101-040-how-to-build-a-search-engine-automatically-grade-essays-and-identify-synonyms-using-latent-semantic-analysis/): 
  - Cosine Angular Separation 
  - Hamming Distance 
  - Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA) or Latent Semantic Indexing (LSI)
These methods are based on semantic similarity.

I also heard some company used tool called [Spacy](https://spacy.io/) to summarize document to compare each other.