# what is the best method to calculate text similarity?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

There are some methods that can retrieve similarity between texts such as wup_similarity() cosine_similarity() etc. My purpose is to make an essay answering system.That means I want to compare the answer sheet and marking scheme. So far I did followings without using any training or modeling approch.

1.pre-processed both documents(removed punctuations,did lemmatization and etc).

2.next I get the similar words by using word-net syn-sets and made an two large arrays (Marking scheme with their synonyms and answer sheet with its synonyms)--possibly not the correct way.

3.Then I needed to compare these two large arrays and want to get similarity value

Can you please help me with this by giving some suggessions or answers. I know that word-net syn-sets are not the best because it will give unrelated answers . 
eg: animal and vehicle will return 1 as similar values.

However I need to find solutions for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256079/best-way-to-compare-meaning-of-text-documents

Answer (score 1):

The standard method that nearly every search engine uses is comparing TF-IDF vectors with cosine similarity. This will probably not do justice to your task, since you are talking about the evaluation of essays given a marking scheme. This would also include checking identity of important propositions (in the sense of verb-argument structures) 
and the rhetoric structure of the answer. This is important because "columbus explored the American continent" may be semantically related to "the American continent explored Columbus" but the latter is obviously non-sense (under the condition that the continent is the subject). Maybe have a look at Discourse Representation Theory (DRT) and the formal logic that needs to be modeled for it. A comparison of DRTs of your texts will do a better job and work for argumentative texts as well.

For DRTs, you might want to start off with this: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/discourse-representation-theory/#DRSLanSynSemAcc. It is quite complicated, as is your application. Another approach would be to use a dependency parser in order to extract the most important propositions from your marking scheme, and then check how many and how similar the relations are compared to some essay answer. For this, you could use similarity measures of vectors or embeddings of the relation (verb) and the arguments with their respective roles ("Subject" and "Object") . I think it is worth trying this before you use full DRTs since that is a hell of a lot of work tailoring it to your domain.

Comment: Thank you so much, can you please give me some references to start with it? It will be great help for me.

Comment: Actually to get the most important words I created an web interface using django. So at first I tokenize the marking scheme into words and assign weights for them. Then I saved that weights in database. After Compare documents with similarity measurement I used weighted sum mechanism to add weights to answer. I need to accurate my similarity measurement. I think this will help.Thanks again